# Adding a menu item to the main menu

Tags: menus

Does anyone know how to ad an item to the menu on the right side of the page.
Please see the photo attached.[image]

I basically want to add "ISSUES" as a menu item on the left side of page. Just like ARTIST is listed. I want to make this change and I dont know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Hope it makes sense if not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, depending on your specific needs.

**Option 1: Create a new post type**

If you need to create a new post type for "Issues", the menu can be created automagically as part of the custom post type registration process. You can use a plugin like [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) or you can register your own by hand (You can use my [Example Post Types & Taxonomies](https://github.com/Veraxus/nv-example-post-types-tax) plugin or an online tool like [GenerateWP.com](http://generatewp.com/post-type/) to make things easier).

**Option 2: Create a custom page**

If you need to create a new page without being attached to a custom post type, I also have an example plugin that demonstrates this exact thing. You can copy the code verbatim and reuse it.

[Download Example Admin Menus Plugin](https://github.com/Veraxus/nv-example-admin-menus) or [just view the code on GitHub](https://github.com/Veraxus/nv-example-admin-menus/blob/master/init.php).

You can also [read up on `add_menu_page()` on the WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) In this case, you will need to provide a callback that builds the page from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom post types (know as CPT)
Take a look at this link
[Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom post type for each new item that you want.

There are two basic steps for each item:

1. Register the new post type. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

   a. When registering a new post type, to show in the menu, two arguments must be set to true: show_ui and show_in_menu.

   b. If you want custom taxonomies (categories/tags) to go with your post type, you will have to register those as well.
2. Create a template to display the new post type pages on the front of the site. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

   a. You will need at least a single-(post-type).php template.

   b. You will need an archive-(post-type).php template, if you want to show the new post-type in list, similar to a blog.

   C.  You will need to create an archive-(taxonomy).php template if you use custom taxonomies.